# Edge of prooftree takes on style of other edge if move by is used twice

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, forest, prooftrees

I use the package [`prooftrees`](http://ctan.triasinformatica.nl/graphics/pgf/contrib/prooftrees/prooftrees.pdf), which is based on the Ti*k*Z `forest`. As I have to draw proofs with many branches, I want some nodes to be lower, which is supported by the "move by" option. However, if I use the move by option twice it seems like the second time I use it the style of the first edge is used to fill the jump within the second edge.

I have simplified the proof in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{prooftrees}

\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}{close with=$\times$, single branches=true, align=center}
    [Mary: \neg CatLady \sqcup \exists hasPet.Cat, just={$\sqsubseteq$}
        [Mary: \exists hasPet.Cat, just={$\sqcup$}, close]
        [Mary: \neg CatLady
        [John: \neg CatLady \sqcup \exists hasPet.Cat, just={$\sqsubseteq$}, move by=1, edge=green
        [John: \exists hasPet.Cat, just={$\sqcup$}, edge=dashed
        [(John{, }Y): hasPet{, } Y: Cat, just={$\exists$}, close={$\sqsubseteq$}, move by=2, edge=dashed]
        ]
        ]
        ]
    ]
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}
```

That gives me the following result:

[image]

The edge between 4 and 5 should be dashed and black completely, but for some reason, there is a green, solid part (which is copied from the edge between 2 and 3). By removing the move by option from eiter of the two edges, this effect does not happen. Furthermore, this only happens when there is a closed branch before the first line that has the move by option.

Does anybody know how to prevent the style of the first edge that uses the option "move by" to be copied to other edges that also use the move by option?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Nice first question. In case you don't get an answer here, you can also email the package author Clea Rees for a solution - this looks like a bug, so she might be interested in hearing about it.

Answer (score 1):

Version 0.7 of `prooftrees` fixes this bug. The update has been uploaded to CTAN and should, therefore, be available shortly.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{prooftrees}

\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}{close with=$\times$, single branches=true, align=center}
    [Mary: \neg CatLady \sqcup \exists hasPet.Cat, just={$\sqsubseteq$}
        [Mary: \exists hasPet.Cat, just={$\sqcup$}, close]
        [Mary: \neg CatLady
        [John: \neg CatLady \sqcup \exists hasPet.Cat, just={$\sqsubseteq$}, move by=1, edge=green
        [John: \exists hasPet.Cat, just={$\sqcup$}, edge=dashed
        [(John{, }Y): hasPet{, } Y: Cat, just={$\exists$}, close={$\sqsubseteq$}, move by=2, edge=dashed, ]
        ]
        ]
        ]
    ]
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}
```

[image: tableau]